# How convert collection of id to collection of beans?

Tags: java, entity, mapstruct

I have some problem.
I have two entity and one DTO.

```
@Entity
class X {
    @OneToMany
    Set<Y> set;
}

@Entity
class Y {
    Long id;
    @ManyToOne
    X x;
}

class XDTO {
    Set<Long> yId;
}
```

How implement mapper in that situation?

```
@Mapper
public mapper() {

    XDTO toDto (X x);
    X toEntity (XDTO xDTO);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
@Mapper(uses=EntityMapper.class)
public interface XMapper() {

    @Mapping(source="set", target="yId")
    XDTO toDto (X x);

    @InheritInverseConfiguration
    X toEntity (XDTO xDTO);
}

public class EntityMapper {

    EntityManager em = ...;

    public <T extends BaseEntity> T resolve(long id, @TargetType Class<T> entityClass) {
        entityManager.find( entityClass, id );
}

    public long toReference(BaseEntity entity) {
        return entity != null ? entity.getId() : null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what you have described, it looks like you want to achieve this:

1. Return XDTO when X entity is passed and,
2. Return X entity when XDTO is passed.

I came up with the following solution:

```
public Mapper{

    // Returns XDTO when X entity is passed as a parameter
    XDTO toDto(X x){
        XDTO temp=new XDTO();
        for(Y y: x.set){
            temp.add(y.id)
        }
        return temp;
    }

    // Returns X entity when XDTO is passed as a parameter
    X toEntity (XDTO xDTO){
        Set<Y> tempSet=new HashSet<Y>();
        for(Long yId:x.set){
            Y ytemp=new Y();
            ytemp.setId(yId);
            tempSet.add(ytemp);
        }
        return tempSet;
    }
}
```